# KVM guest in local network using bridge - I can see VM

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, bridge, local

I create bridge br0 (10.10.10.2) which use phisical eno2 and vnet0 for VM (10.10.10.121).
On Host everything is OK i see VM, VM see Host and Internet. BUT ... I can't See VM from  other computers in network 10.10.10.0. Can you help me ?

```
$:ifconfig 
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.10.10.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.10.10.255
        inet6 fe80::d294:66ff:fe66:7c42  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d0:94:66:66:7c:42  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 7141  bytes 956262 (956.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3936  bytes 400056 (400.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
eno2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether d0:94:66:66:7c:42  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 456201  bytes 554903479 (554.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 324318  bytes 127110834 (127.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 18
```

```
$ brctl show
br0             8000.d09466667c42       no              eno2
                                                        vnet0
                                                        vnet1
```

```
$ arp -an
? (192.168.0.210) at 2c:ea:7f:f7:53:ae [ether] on eno1
? (192.168.0.1) at e0:23:ff:2c:5a:dd [ether] on eno1
? (10.10.10.121) at 52:54:00:7e:5d:0e [ether] on br0
? (10.10.10.1) at e0:23:ff:2c:5a:d8 [ether] on br0
```

```
$:bridge link show
3: eno2 state UP : <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 4
102: vnet0 state UNKNOWN : <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 100
```

```
$ ip link show master br0
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:94:66:66:7c:42 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
102: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:7e:5d:0e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: Can you tell more about "VM from other computers in network 10.10.10.0"? You should use tools like ping and tcpdump to see where packets are going etc.

Comment: I can ping only from VM to 10.10.10.0 and World.  I cannot ping from any machine from 10.10.10.0 to VM.